# Previous state stored in variable changes too when state change in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to implement like and dislike functionality for posts.

I changed state when user like/dislike post and send request to server and if request failed I changed state to previous state. But previous state change to new state to and I don't know why.

```js
export const dislikePostAction = (
    postId: string,
): ThunkAction<Promise<void>, RootState, {}, AnyAction> => {
    return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>, getState): Promise<void> => {
        console.log(getState().GroupPosts.posts); // Even here is new state
        const prevState = getState().GroupPosts.posts;
        console.log(prevState);
        const newState = prevState.map(item => {
            if (item.postId === postId) {
                const newPost = item;
                if (newPost.currentUserLiked === UserPostLike.DISLIKE) {
                    newPost.likeCount = item.likeCount + 1;
                    newPost.currentUserLiked = UserPostLike.NO_ACTION;
                } else {
                    newPost.likeCount = item.likeCount - 1;
                    newPost.currentUserLiked = UserPostLike.DISLIKE;
                }
                return newPost;
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        });
        console.log(prevState);
        dispatch(setPosts(newState));
        const response = await PostsApi.dislikePost(postId);
        if (!response.success) {
            console.log(prevState); // prev state here is same as newState
            dispatch(setPosts(prevState));
        }
    };
};
```

I am using `redux` with `redux-thunk`

Comment: You are mutating state in the action.

Comment: @HMR I store `newState` to new variable.

Comment: I think you have trouble understanding what an object reference is in JavaScript: `newPost = item` means that newPost and item both point to the same object so `newPost.likeCount = item.likeCount + 1;` mutates newPost but because it points to the same reference as item it mutates item as well, you can try `const newPost = {...item};` to set newPost to a **shallow copy** of item. Maybe [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md#value-vs-reference) can help

Comment: @HMR I did that but I get typescript error for their types. I changed it to `new Post(item)` and now is ok. tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create new `Post` object with `new Post(item)` and problem solved.

```
const newPost = new Post(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are assigning `newState` to `prevState` and not mutating it so it will refer to address of `prevState` in the memory and it will change the `prevState` instead you should create a new Obj or array by mutating `prevState` like so :
if array :

```
   const prevState =[... getState().GroupPosts.posts];
```

if Object:

```
 const prevState ={... getState().GroupPosts.posts};
```

or you can use `Object.assign()` which will create a new Object and not refer to the `prevState` address in memory.